# Sum of 2 pivot rank columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a table and already have the pivot table with indepedent rank, as seen in the picture.

However, I have no idea how can I create the column "Final_rank" as the sum of 2 independent ranks from pivot table. Any chance we can do that as calculated field?

[My Data and Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiIdU.png)

Comment: You can't do that in a regular pivot table. You can do it in PowerPivot with a DAX measure. Nevertheless, I'm not sure whether it's a good idea to sum ranks. What are you trying to represent with that sum?

Comment: I agree with Flex, where I'm not sure that summing ranks would tell a good story. I would probably come up with another score in your data, one that uses Score and Quality. Then your pivot can rank on that column.

Comment: So you mean to have a third variable is averaged by normalized quality and score (they should be normalized to have the same scale)?

Comment: Hope this blog "[Nested Calculations In Power Query](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2015/05/11/nested-calculations-in-power-query)"could be helpful. Or you get the rank for different Group in data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You need to so this:*

[image]

- Since you have finished with basics, then only you have to insert additional field to the PT, called as **Calculated Field.**

**How it works:**

- Select PT & check the Analyze TAB above.
- Find & hit Field, Items & Sets.
- Then hit Calculated field.
- Now use the dialogue as shown with screen shot.

[image]

- Finish with OK.

**N.B.**

- If required you may insert Subtotal & Grand Total also.
- Column Names are also editable.

Comment: @Linh NV glad to help you ,,, keep asking ☺